# Heap dump not generated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, heap-dump

I have already added `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="C:\hd.hprof"` to Default VM arguments but I don't know why the heap dump file not generated when `OutOfMemoryError` thrown. Can anyone halp me?

More details:

- My JRE version is 1.7.0_02
- The heap dump is generated once for the first time but when I change HeapDumpPath, it not generated anymore. Already revert HeapDumpPath to be the same as the first time but heap dump still not generated
- File `C:\hd.hprof` already exists.
- Below image is the eclipse dialog when I force close eclipse. In that dialog, I can see that eclipse have included my arguments ]![Below image is the eclipse dialog when I force closing eclipse. In that dialog, I can see that eclipse have included my arguments

[image]

Thanks you.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with permissions, you could try another path like C:\TEMP. But don't ask where the c:\hd.prof comes from ;-)

Comment: I don't think so because I have already tried many different paths but the result is still the same.

Comment: Because the application I want to get heap dump when OutOfMem Exeption thrown is an Android application.

Answer (score 1):

Some thrown heap overflows are not real overflows, but are thrown directly after calculation.In fact, there is no overflow, so no heap dump will be generated.For example, when using DirectByteBuffer